# SQL Query return highest date value in query

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Im trying to run a query to do the following:
return all of the most recent entries in the table between a given date range.
Currently I am using this query

`SELECT id FROM schedule WHERE eventdate BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-07'`

Which returns records 1,2,3,4,5 from the schedule table thats shown below

schedule table.

```
+----+------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+----------+
| id | eventdate  | resource_id |      text       |  added_on  | added_by |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+----------+
|  1 | 2014-09-05 |           1 | Some old text   | 2014-08-01 | Sam      |
|  2 | 2014-09-05 |           1 | Some newer text | 2014-09-01 | Jordan   |
|  3 | 2014-09-06 |           1 | another day     | 2014-09-03 | Jordan   |
|  4 | 2014-09-05 |           1 | Most recent     | 2014-09-10 | Jordan   |
|  5 | 2014-09-07 |           2 | Other resource  | 2014-09-09 | Sam      |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+----------+
```

I'm trying to only return the unique records within the specified date range, where the unique records that should be returned are those with the highest date timestamp in the `added_on` column.

In the example above I would like for only records 3,4,5 to be returned. Records 1 and 2 have been superseded by record 4.

**Please note: The `added_on` column is of type date timestamp (yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss) and has been left off for clarity **

I do not know the number of rows the query will return, the information that determines the uniqueness of the record is the `eventdate, resource_id and added_on`
i.e. there should only be one record returned per resource per day, and this record should have the highest added_on value

Comment: what determines that rows 1,2 are superseded by 3?

Comment: there is a column which always remains the same (EventID)?

Comment: why is id 3 returned? It should be superseded too, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s1.* FROM schedule s1  
inner join (select max(id) as id1 from schedule WHERE eventdate BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-07' group by eventdate,resource_id ) as s2 on s2.id1=s1.id
```

It will work for you

Answer (score 1):

## NOTE:

you said you determine the uniqueness of each day by the three columns eventdate, resource_id, and added_on... but you only want the greatest added_on per day... so do not group by added_on.. group by eventdate to get data by day, group by eventdate, resource_id to get data by day per resource_id.

try getting the unique id's and then filter an outer query by them

```
SELECT * 
FROM schedule
WHERE ID IN
(   SELECT MAX(id) 
    FROM schedule 
    WHERE eventdate BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-07' 
    GROUP BY eventdate, resource_id
)
```

[DEMO1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6b5be/1)

or if you want to use the highest added_on you can do it the same way

```
SELECT * 
FROM schedule
WHERE added_on IN
(   SELECT MAX(added_on) 
    FROM schedule 
    WHERE eventdate BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-07' 
    GROUP BY eventdate, resource_id
)
```

[DEMO2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6b5be/2)

if you want to get rid of using IN and use a JOIN you can do it with a JOIN on MAX() added on.

```
SELECT * 
FROM schedule s
JOIN 
(   SELECT MAX(added_on) as added_on 
    FROM schedule
    WHERE eventdate BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-07' 
    GROUP BY eventdate, resource_id
) t ON t.added_on = s.added_on
```

[DEMO3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6b5be/9)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the latest record for every unique combination of eventdate, resource_id, added_on, like this:

```
SELECT schedule.* 
FROM schedule JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id 
   FROM schedule
   GROUP BY eventdate, resource_id, added_on
) t
ON t.max_id = schedule.id
WHERE eventdate BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-07'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be the simplest query you can have. Just comment here if you have further question.

```
 SELECT MAX(id) , eventdate, Max(added_on) FROM schedule GROUP BY eventdate.
```

This will return

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | eventdate  |  added_on  | 
+----+------------+------------+
|  3 | 2014-09-06 | 2014-09-03 | 
|  4 | 2014-09-05 | 2014-09-10 | 
|  5 | 2014-09-07 | 2014-09-09 | 
+----+------------+------------+
```

Comment: LAST doesn't exist in MySQL just as a fyi

Comment: At this point you are basically faking a row.. What if the OP wants more than just the id eventdate and added_on? The rows wouldnt match up.

Comment: yeah you're right. I just based my answer on the output that Jordan wants. Well if he needs more fields than that he should use a select within a select just like your answer below. However, a query with select within a select runs too slow. so why will you use a query that runs slow if you don't need it? use it when it's necessary.